# Omega theme background color problems

Tags: 7, theming

What would be the best option for achieving following:

I need to have a background color blue under website and the body of the website (including all regions) would be white. Best for demonstrating would be to visit this site

> http://www.prevention.com/health/healthy-living/50-healthiest-eco-spas-america

By default `alpha-default-normal-12.css` contains rule for body `min-width: 960px`. I can solve it by changing body width to `width:960px` and adding `margin: 0 auto;`.

However after switching to fluid layout, width is taken from my `global.css` and it of course restricts layout to be fluid.

My question is what would be best way to achieve this without editing other css files. Or is it ok to edit them?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `global.css` insted of editing `alpha_default_normal.css` so that changes will persists even if you changes your browser resolution. And according to me, set the width of the div in percentage... so it will automatically adjust to other screen resolutions.
eg.

```
width:70%;
margin : 0 auto;
```

Comment: Hi,Problem is that I need the page to have on almost all pages width 960px and on one content type I need it to behave fluid and cover 100% width.